# get DOM element from AJAX response with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have an AJAX request that returns a chunk of HTML as a response that is inserted into a div.  How can I use JavaScript to get an element of DOM from that AJAX response HTML?  I have JavaScript at the end of the returned HTML response div, but getElementById returns null,  apparently because the DOM hasn't been created, and I can't use window.onload like on a normal web page.  See eample below.  And this has to be in JavaScript - no libraries.

```
<div class="page-content extractAjaxContent" id="tableContent_AJAX">
<div id="name">Biff</div>
    <html:form action="/variableCostStatusPost" method="post">
     ....some JSP to produce HTML
    </html:form>
<script>console.log("Name is " + document.getElementById('name'));</script>
</div>
```

Comment: yourdiv.getElementById or another dom selector function?

Comment: Once it's insert into a DIV, you can use ordinary DOM searching functions like `div.getElementById()` to get elements.

Comment: I added an example to get the question unheld.

Comment: @Barmar how is what you're saying different from document.getElementById()?

Comment: In the case of `getElementById()` there's no difference between applying it to `document` or `div`, since IDs have to be unique. But if you use other functions, such as `getElementsByClassName()`, applying it to `div` restricts the search to that DIV.

Comment: Anything that depends on the response to AJAX needs to be done in its `onreadystatechange` handler function, not in top-level script code.

Comment: In your example code, which div are you inserting the ajax response data into? is it tableContent_AJAX? In your example code, it seems like console.log statement will be executed before the response is inserted into the div. Your call to document.getElementById ('name'') will return some value only AFTER the response is added to the div, so like Barmar said, it should be done on onreadystatechange (i.e. ajax success callback function).

Comment: There are a bunch of pages with AJAX in the app.  There is one AJAX request/response function.  If I write this extra function in the success method, how do I have it only run in the couple of needed cases?

Comment: So if I get it right, you have 1 common ajax function that you invoke to make calls to different urls, and you need to run your specific code of getElementById for only couple of cases. And you are inserting the response inside a div for ALL the cases, and not just few select cases. Is that correct? I guess you'll either need to know from the response when do you want to execute this new function or you can have your function accept a callback function (optional), and execute that instead of regular callback. Now pass a custom callback from areas where you need to execute your special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, depending on which browsers you need to support:

1. If you need to support all browsers, put your `console.log` code into the "success" function that's called after the ajax response. This will ensure it runs only after the div is updated by ajax.
2. If you only need to support HTML5-compatible browsers, listen to the `DOMNodeInserted` event on the "name" div and instead of changing it via `innerHTML`, create and append the html code objects

Comment: Looks like you have to grab it out of the response object in the success method of the AJAX code.

Answer (score 1):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/wxCJL/1/

In this example the `setTimeout` call simulates the ajax request's `success` function, and the variable `responseData` is a placeholder for the HTML returned by the server.

**Script**

```
function onLoad() {
    var holder = document.getElementById('content');

    //simulate ajax call
    setTimeout(function() {
       // this code will be in the success handler

        var responseData = "<div><strong>Here I Come</strong> to save the day!</div>";
        holder.innerHTML = responseData;
    }, 2500);
}
```

**Html**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div>
   Where is the content?
   <span id='content'></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but not really what I'm talking about. Yours is a variation of writing some text into a div.

Comment: i'm not sure why you say so.  this is how you add an element to the dom without using  a framework.  the variable `responseData` is a placeholder for the HTML returned by your server.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I just tried to undo my downvote but SO wouldn't let me.