# When using AJAX, current page can't get the responded DOM elements, and the JavaScript doesn't work either

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

In my current page, there's a sorting function which will send criteria through AJAX to another php file to do the query then return result to the current page.

The following function is triggered by clicking a button on the current page:

```
function refineResult(){
                     var setStatus = document.getElementById("sortByStatus").value;
                     var setSales = document.getElementById("sortBySales").value;
                     var setRecordCount = document.getElementById("recordPerPage").value;

                     var xmlhttp;
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                            }
                         else
                                    {// code for IE6, IE5
                                         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                         }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                         {
                           document.getElementById("showTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                         }
                }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","showWorkOrder.php?selectStatus="+setStatus+"&selectSales="+setSales+"&selectCount="+setRecordCount+"&orderby="+sortingKey+"&direction="+direction,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

                 }
```

Result will be returned and display to the following element in current page:

```
<div id="showTable"></div>
```

Problem 1: I can't access any DOM element returned by AJAX result. On a loaded page, I checked the source code and the browser is showing the above element without the exact html code that AJAX returned.

Problem 2: Since I can't access any DOM element from AJAX result, I try to include JavaScript in the other php file to manipulate the query result, however, the JS doesn't seem to work on the return result either.

For testing purpose, I make a `<div id='test'></div>` in the html part of the other php file, then use JS to simply set the innerHTML of the div element, but on my current page, the content doesn't show up.

So how can I use JS to access to the elements return by AJAX result? Thank you.

Comment: You must wait until said elements exist before you attempt to access them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by including the JS into the "success" function of the AJAX code. Got this answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041060/get-dom-element-from-ajax-response-with-javascript)

Is it a good practice though?